# Image button displaying 'Submit query' over the top of image in Firefox

Tags: css, image, firefox, web

My project is displaying correctly in both IE and chrome.  However in FF for some reason the image button displays 'Submit query' over the top of it.  I am setting the image location in CSS and it is definitely correct as it is working correctly in all browsers, its just that FireFox for some reason plasters 'Submit Query' over the top on each image button.

Here is my CSS:

```
.NavModuleTabs A.NavModuleSelectedWide1
{
color: #555555;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-top: 5px;
height: 25px;
background-image: url(../Images/NavBar/NavModuleTab_125.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-weight: bold;
width: 130px;
display: block;
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas why this happens?  I found a few solutions via google but nothing has worked for me so far.

Thank you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add this attribute to your button:

```
value=""
```

Comment: You sir are an utter legend, I can't imagine I would have discovered that in a million years!

Answer (score 1):

Text-indent: -9999px; add this to your css

Answer (score 1):

also add *css* **display:block** and

> Text-indent: -9999px;

Then it will work in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

still comes top in the google list so adding my 2 cents worth: the answers above work but don't address the cause; in our case it was the missing imageurl after replacing it with css like the above, in which case one simple solution is to use a linkbutton instead