# APS .NET Image button displaying 'Submit query' over the top of image in IE10

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a similar problem like [Image button displaying 'Submit query' over the top of image in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977520/image-button-displaying-submit-query-over-the-top-of-image-in-firefox). I have an submit button without text but only an image. Unfortunately I see "Submit query" text over the image.

My CSS is

```
.cssFilterButtonImg
{
    background-image:url(Icons/ButtonSave_Filter.gif);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-width:1px;    
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-left: 0.1em; 
    margin-top: 0.3em; 
    margin-right: 0em; 
    padding: 0em; 
    font-weight:  400; 
    font-size: 11px ;
    font-family:Arial; 
    vertical-align:top;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    /*filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#c2d0db');
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Wave(Add='true', LightStrength=60, Phase=20, Strength=0,  Freq=1)
    text-align:right;
    text-indent:12px;
    color: #04233e;*/
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
 }
```

I already have attribute value="" in my aspx file:

```
<input class="cssFilterButtonImg" type="submit" id="btnSaveFilter" value="" runat="server" />
```

I also have 2 buttons with text:

```
<input class="cssFilterButton" type="submit" id="btnApplyFilter" value="" runat="server" />
```

When I run application I see this in aspx:

```
<input name="btnSaveFilter" class="cssFilterButtonImg" id="btnSaveFilter" onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate(''); " type="submit" value="Submit Query"/>
```

I have this issue in IE10 and Opera.

I suppose that the problem is very small, but I can not find it. Any suggestions, how can I solve this?

Comment: you could use [text-indent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)

Comment: 10x [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete), `text-indent` helps. Although situation is very strange. In all cases the text inside is "Submit query" even I put some other text in ASPX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comment of @Pete (`text-indent`) - this helps me. All credits to him.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try 
`value=" "`
instead of 
`value=""`

The space should do the trick.