# Remove Submit Query From dynamically added Image Button

Tags: c#, imagebutton

I am working on c# website.in one of this page i need to add dynamically means by code side  image  button,but it shows submit query.So,now my question is how can i remove this submit query from dynamically added image button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are doing something like this to add ImageButton :

```
      ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
      FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(strFileName);
      imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/img/abc.png";
      imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
      imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
```

I suggest you to set `value` attribute to empty string `""` like this :

```
imageButton.Attributes["value"]="";
```

OR

```
imageButton.Attributes.Add("value", "");
```

Also refer to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977549/1531476)

Hope this helps !